# block as parameter or return value for C function

Tags: objective-c, c

I have a property like this on a class:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) void (^ifSuccess)(MyClass *myObject);
```

Now I need to do this inside a C function:

```
if (self.ifSuccess) {
   self.ifSuccess(value);
}
```

but this will not work, because inside a C function I will not have references to self. So I need to pass the block as a parameter to the C function. Something like this:

```
void myFunction(myClass *object, XXX) {

}
```

where XXX is probably

```
void(^ifSuccess)()
```

making the function like

```
void myFunction(myClass *object, void(^ifSuccess)()) {

}
```

**Please confirm if this is correct.**

The problem is that I cannot pass self.ifSuccess in a call to myFunction.

This will not work

```
myFunction(object, self.ifSuccess);
```

so I need a way to read self.ifSuccess block and pass it to the function.

How?

note: yes, this needs to be in C

Comment: I don't know enough obj-C to answer all of your question, but the syntax `void(^ifSuccess)()` is _not_ valid C.  The circumflex, `^`, is meaningless in that context.

Comment: blocks generally love circumflexes...

Comment: In plain "C"? There are "blocks" in plain "C"?

Comment: @Eric: yes. Blocks is an extension to C, not Objective-C

Comment: Ah!  It's a non-standard Apple extension to C (and C++ and Objective-C)  No wonder I was confoozed!  Thanks... I learned something :)

Comment: "This will not work:" - define "will not work". If you are calling this at an appropriate place, and you have a property on your class called `ifSuccess`, then it definitely should work.

Comment: @Eric blocks are very muck like function pointers not exactly same  but you can draw an analogy

Comment: @amar Yep, otherwise known as "Lambda Expressions" :)  I knew they were in C++11, but hadn't realized they existed in an Apple extension!  Thanks...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ONE:-**Yes you can pass reference to self inside c method.

**TWO:-**Declaring objective c block can be syntactically daunting so I like to be little systematic.

i will do

```
typedef void (^ifSuccess)(MyClass *myObject);
```

now i will declare the property as

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) ifSuccess mySuccessBlock;
```

your function becomes

```
void myFunction(myClass *object,ifSuccess blockParameter) {

}
```

Comment: ok, but Xcode will not let you do use self.ifSuccess on a call to **myFunction(object, self.ifSuccess);**

Comment: ifSuccess is your block type your variable is mySuccessBlock i.e ifSuccess is NSArray and mySuccessBlock is your array variable. do self.mySuccessBlock

Comment: ok, I am talking outside that function. Xcode will not let I call myFunction using self.ifSuccess as a parameter.

Comment: buddy property (nonatomic, strong) ifSuccess mySuccessBlock; make this property now its analogous to   property (nonatomic, strong) NSArry *myArray;   you do not do self.NSArry  you do self.myArray so here please do self.mySuccessBlock(<pass here the parameter>).

Comment: you are not understanding the problem. Create a project with the answer you gave and try to run myFunction passing that self.mySuccessBlock as parameter.

Comment: use of undeclared identifier self

Comment: @RubberDuck 1. Xcode has nothing to do with this. 2. It is unclear where you are getting this error -- when calling the C function or inside its implementation?

Comment: just found the problem. A typo. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @RubberDuck Do copy the blocks (nonatomic, copy).